# Why do Australian, Canadian and English lawyers pronounce "versus (v.)" as "and"? Isn't "and" more confusing?

Tags: legal-terms

1. Why doesn't the Commonwealth pronounce *versus* naturally, or as "vee, as [Americans do](https://reason.com/volokh/2020/11/02/how-do-you-pronounce-the-v-in-a-case-name-like-the-letter-v-or-like-versus/)?
2. Doesn't pronouncing *v.* as "and" unnecessarily cause confusion? Presuppose that Litigants 1 and 2  are suing 3 and 4. Then *1 and 2* **`vs.`** *3 and 4* is clear. But *1 and 2* **`and`** *3 and 4* is ambiguous, particularly orally!

## [Research](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/oakes-v-regina-v-pronounced-as-and-or-versus.3199470/post-16194347)

I quote the Canadian Guide to Uniform Legal Citation ("*McGill Guide*"), [Rule 3.3](http://web5.uottawa.ca/www2/rl-lr/eng/legal-citations/1_16-style_cause.html).

> the "v” is commonly pronounced as "and”.

#### Australia

I quote the Australian Government's Style Manual.

> [In civil case titles, the ‘v’ is pronounced ‘and’. In criminal case titles, the ‘v’ is pronounced ‘against’.](https://www.stylemanual.gov.au/referencing-and-attribution/legal-material/cases-and-legal-authorities#civil_and_criminal_case_titles_have_different_elements)

I quote James Cook University.

> [- v stands for the Latin word versus which means against (spoken as 'and' in civil cases and 'against' in criminal cases)](https://libguides.jcu.edu.au/law/help-with/understanding-case-citation)

#### UK

John McGarry, *Acing the LLB* (2006), page 157.

> When speaking case names, remember, in UK law, we do not say ‘vee’ or ‘versus’.
> So, we do not say ‘Donoghue vee Stevenson’ or ‘Donoghue versus Stevenson’.
> Rather, in civil cases, we say ‘and’. So, *Donoghue v Stevenson* is spoken as
> ‘*Donoghue and Stevenson*’.

Sharon Hanson, *Learning Legal Skills and Reasoning* (2016, 4th edn), page 184.

> The notation
> signifying the prosecution is the italicised letter *v*, which stands for the Latin ‘versus’,
> meaning ‘against’. However, if you are speaking and refer to the citation the reference to ‘v’ is always ‘*and*’ not ‘versus’.

Comment: English folks seem entirely happy to pronounce things entirely differently from how they are spelled. It's not just legal terms. They're even worse when it comes to place names.

Comment: Also, FYI, in E&W **criminal** cases "*R v Jones*" is spoken as "*the Crown against Jones*" and not, as some might say "*Harvey Jones*" - I'm not sure about the Commonwealth but I'd guess it would be the same –

Comment: Don't put much weight on what the McGill Guide says. E.g. https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=36783&id=2016/2016-12-02--36783&date=2016-12-02&fp=n&audio=n (McLachlin C.J. saying, "Her Majesty the Queen in Right of Canada **versus** Kevin Antic"); https://www.scc-csc.ca/case-dossier/info/webcastview-webdiffusionvue-eng.aspx?cas=36602&id=2016/2016-12-06--36602&date=2016-12-06&fp=n&audio=n (McLachlin C.J. saying, "Google Inc. **versus** ... Equustek Solutions Inc.") And these were just the first two examples I looked up.